# xtreme download manager weird behavior

Tags: xubuntu

Just Downloaded Xtereme-Download manger works fine but one problem when i am using Facebook and and when there is sound of Notification or chat the xtreme-download manger asks to download it's audio and always disturb me.
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

From the program main window access tools menu > options > file types.. you will find many files extensions delete MP3 extension and save then restart the program. Good luck!